# Logging error when executing Maven SonarQube plugin

Tags: maven, logging, sonarqube

I've been facing an issue with Maven SonarQube plugin (v2.6) when Maven version is recent (strictly larger than 3.1).

Here is what I run:

```
mvn clean verify -Psonar
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar -Psonar
```

The first invocation makes sure sources are compiled and JaCoCo agent is prepared.

The interesting part comes, when the second command is run:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project merlin-schema: Error setting Log implementation.  Cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: org/slf4j/Marker -> [Help 1]
```

Any fix to be published?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing default Maven logging implementation is currently not supported. Ticket created: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MSONAR-122

Comment: Ok, fixed the command. I still get an error related to logging, though not the same. No issue with Maven 3.1.1, Maven 3.2.2 and 3.3.3 fail.

Comment: FYI I'm using Maven 3.2.2 without any issue. Do you have changed default logging implementation of Maven (for example I read that it is possible to replace logback by log4j2 to get console colorization)?

Comment: Right, I'm using https://github.com/jcgay/maven-color with Maven 3.2.2 (not active with 3.3.3 tho).

Comment: I have reproduced, thanks. Ticket created. Should be fixed in next version of the SQ Maven plugin.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm also encountering this error. Im using spring boot with aspectj-maven-plugin plugin. Could this be the reason? Here's my pom: http://textuploader.com/a5y78

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue on bamboo. Use the gwt-maven-plugin.

Comment: Do you have any estimations when new (2.7) plugin will be released?

Comment: Very likely early November.

Comment: is this bug fixed?? i am using Sonar 5.1.2 and maven 3.2.3. Still i am facing the same issue.